# How do I install the stock CentOS repositories?

Tags: centos, yum

I have a situation where the stock repo files that should exist in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` (like `centos-base.repo`) are not present. I need to get them installed. I am sure this is simple, but after hours of searching, it seems I am not googling it correctly.

Basically I have a server with custom repos that are useless to me. I need epel, and epel needs `centos-base.repo`. I also need postgres repo.

Comment: or u can install OS on a virtual machine and later copy the default file located in yum.repos.d directory

Answer (score 25):

Create a file called Centos-Base.repo in the following directory /etc/yum.repos.d

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Base.repo
```

Put the following info inside of the file:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=addons
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=2

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=
$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=2
```

Save it and run.

```
yum clean all
```

Then run.

```
yum repolist
```

If you're copying this into putty via `vi` then make sure you double check line breaks.  I had to fix some editing that happened during the copy-paste.

Comment: Instead of pasting into an editor like vi or vim, just use cat > filename and press ctrl-d after pasting. Also, vim has a mode designed for receiving data from the clipboard, which will disable auto formatting, etc. Just use ":set paste" before entering insert mode. But I still prefer the cat method, it's simpler.

Comment: Why does this have GPG files for CEntOS-5, e.g. 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
?

Comment: It doesn't work on CentOS-7

Comment: For the FYI of posterity who now come to this question: those URLs are no longer valid for CentOS 5. You can use this instead: http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/5.7/ (adjusting for your version of course) . I found that URL at the bottom of this page: http://vault.centos.org/centos/

Answer (score 11):

You could manually reinstall the `centos-release`-rpm using:

```
rpm -ivh --replacepkgs --replacefiles centos-release*.rpm
```

Comment: This worked, but it needed modification. The first step is to see if the centos-release package is installed, by typing rpm -q centos-release. If it's not installed, then the --replacepkgs --replacefiles part of the command should be omitted. In my case the whole thing had been deinstalled, so I used: rpm -Uvh centos-release.*.rpm

Comment: @Jim that must have been a brutal removal of that rpm - without dependency-check. I checked with `yum remove centos-release` - that should normally deinstall the whole system.

Comment: This doesnt work. rpm -ivh --replacepkgs --replacefiles centos-release*.rpm

Answer (score 3):

For me problem solved by clean all repositories and adding new ones from [here](https://tecadmin.net/top-5-yum-repositories-for-centos-rhel-systems) considering my CentOS version:

```
# yum clean all

# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://dl.atrpms.net/all/atrpms-repo-7-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Comment: The first URL is no longer valid. Haven't checked the others.

Comment: Doesnt work if you don't have yum instaleld...

Comment: Actually doesnt work at all