# How to add default yum repositories for CentOS 7.3?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I've installed CentOs 7 on my server and realized for some unknown reasons (*at least by me*), default yum repositories doesn't not work.

for example I tried `yum install vim` but got

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>
> One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),  and yum doesn't
>   have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only  safe
>   thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
>
> ```
>  1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
>
>  2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
>     upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
>     distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
>     packages for the previous distribution release still work).
>
>  3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
>         yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...
>
>  4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
>     will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
>     again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
>
>         yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
>     or
>         subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>
>
>  5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
>     Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
>     so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
>     slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
>     compromise:
>
>         yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
> ```
>
> Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: addons/7

I searched through the net to realize what's the problem and couldn't find anything. So I decided I should add the default repositories which should've been added by default myself.

But I couldn't find out how.

So is there a way to do that and make yum work?

The link which I've downloaded CentOs 7:

http://mirror.teklinks.com/centos/7.3.1611/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso

**EDIT 2**

By cleaning all repositories and adding new ones from here considering my CentOS version the error is gone:

```
# yum clean all

# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://dl.atrpms.net/all/atrpms-repo-7-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

# rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

But now by running `yum install vim` I get:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>   * epel: ftp.riken.jp
>   * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
>   * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
>   No package vim available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

Comment: `rpm -Uvh http://mirror.rackspace.com/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Follw this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/repository-files-missing-centos-6 RHEL-7 : In place of 6 ,put 7 in CentOS-Base.repo file.

Answer (score 9):

You neglected to add the default CentOS 7.x repos which is likely why you're running into your issue. Incidentally, you can fix this issue by grabbing yet another RPM:

```
$ rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

**NOTE:** You can find out what RPM to acquire using `rpm` to query to see what RPM provides a given file. In our case these files:

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-* | sort -u
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Once we re-install this RPM, it'll refresh our .repo files for the base repositories under `/etc/yum.d`. If we didn't know the URL where to download it, again, we can inquire to RPM to find out.

First take note of the name of the RPM:

```
$ rpm -qi centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64 | grep Name
Name        : centos-release
```

Then search on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/centos-release) for this shortname, which will lead you to the URL I showed above in the `rpm -ivh ...` command.

**NOTE:** The same steps can be applied for CentOS 7.3, or whatever version of CentOS you're currently using.

Answer (score 1):

The files that configure the source of the repos are in

```
/etc/yum.conf
/etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

Verify that those files have the correct repo links. Specially the one in `/etc/yum/repos.d`

You may need sudo access to edit them. They are the equivalent of `/etc/apt/sources.list` of debian based systems

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make sure if they are correct links?

Comment: See this related [how do I install the stock centos repositories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52666/how-do-i-install-the-stock-centos-repositories)

Comment: I've copied the text from the link you suggested to `Centos-Base.repo` in `/etc/yum/repos.d/` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/*`. I'm getting this error `Could not retrieve mirrorlist error was 14: curl#56 - “Recv failure: Connection reset by peer”` and posted a new question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370812/112017) I appreciate if you take a look at it