# Setting up DNF on Yocto

Tags: package-management, repository, dnf, yocto, petalinux

I am using PetaLinux (or Yocto) as my systems OS.

I built the image and have `dnf` as my package manager.
However, when I try to install something, I get the error message:

> Error: There are no enabled repos.

So this means, my repo list is empty, I suppose. The question is, I want to be able to just install packages easily without always adding a repo or the url to the repo to install it.

So is there some kind of URL I could source or add to my configuration file, where many common packages are linked with repo?

I want to be able to just do something like `sudo dnf install python3`. Is this somehow possible? What do I have to do to get there?

Thank you very much in advance!

### Edit

I tried installing yum on my Ubuntu and then checking the repolist, but it is also empty. Where do I get standard repos from, so I can access many different packages?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't really fit, because Yocto is not CentOS, but I was able to use [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52666/how-do-i-install-the-stock-centos-repositories) to install a standard repository. If there is a better fitting standard repo list, I'd like to know, but this is the one I'm currently working with.